# Removing Border from ListView

Tags: android, listview, colors, border

I have this issue I have been trying to remove for a while and now I am thinking it is not possible but anyway here is my issue. I either need the border around the listview changed colour or the border removed to allow the background colour to show.

[image]

Here you can see the grey dividers but I need the white border going around the edge of the screen removed or the colour changed to the colour of the grey dividers which is #e5e5e5. The border thing looks a lot like a framelayout or a margin but I cannot find any code to make it actually create a border. I could then do a correct margin for the listview and the colours should all look correct and decent. Thanks for the assistance and ask for any code that may be required.

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#e5e5e5" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#e5e5e5"
    android:dividerHeight="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_card"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background_card"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"      
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView     
        android:id="@+id/list_image"   
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/rihanna"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Title Of Song-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans" 
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- Artist Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/artist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Just gona stand there and ..." />

<!-- Rightend Duration -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="5:45"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <!-- Rightend Arrow -->    
 <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your xml code

Comment: @GokhanArik Added the two xml files that it uses

Comment: Now turn on GPU overdraw and watch the green and red shades appear. You should consider optimizing the backgrounds to reduce overdraw. From the looks of it, an appropriate window background and list item background should be enough to get the same effect.

Comment: @MH I will start optimising as soon as I get this part finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Main.xml`, add `android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"` and `android:layout_marginRight="6dp"` to your `ListView`. This will give you grey border on either side of the `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#e5e5e5" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:divider="#e5e5e5"
        android:dividerHeight="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_card"/>

</LinearLayout>
```